# How to prevent passing className and style props to component in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

Hi I have a custom button component. This button component should accept all ButtonHTMLAttributes except for className and style to prevent devs from adding their own styles. I am using TypeScript with React. How can I achieve this? I tried using Omit but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you can do is you can overwrite the styles and classNames properties like:

```
function CustomButton = (props> => {
   return (
      <button {...props} className={""} style={{}}/>
   ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you annotated types. But you can try the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) concept.

```
function Button({className, style, ...restProps}) {
    // Use the restProps object
}
```